# Handling unit tests with a condition on the current time

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, tdd

I'm taking a stab at setting up unit tests for some utility classes in a project I'm working on, and one of the classes (contains licensing info) has a method that does some determination based on the current time.

i.e. the license contains an expiry date, and the license string validates that date, but the actual logic to see if the license is expired is based on the current time.

```
public boolean isValid()
{
    return isLicenseStringValid() && !isExpired();
}

public boolean isExpired()
{
    Date expiry = getExpiryDate();
    if( expiry == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    Date now = new Date();

    return now.after( expiry );
}
```

So, I'm not sure what to do, since the 'new Date()' thing isn't a static criterion.

1. Should I not bother to test 'isValid', and just test 'isLicenseStringValid()' and the 'getExpiryDate()' function separately?
2. Do I just use a license key in the test with a crazy long expiry such that I'll have switched jobs by the time it expires?
3. Do I try to mock out 'new Date()' to some 'getCurrentTime()' method such that I can fake what time it is now?

What do others normally do with tests that are time-conditional?

Comment: BTW, I see a problem in your code other than date logic:

    if( expiry == null ) {
        return false;
    }

I don't think you should return `false` on `isExpired()` method if the expiry date is null.
For more information, read - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fail_securely

Comment: It's a license object that has two possible modes: 
1. perpetual with no expiry date (hence the above)
2. temporary with an expiry date

so, it is correct that if there is no expiry date set, it isn't expired.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Definitely mock out `new Date()`.

Create a `Clock` interface with a `getCurrentTime()` method or something similar. That way you can have a `FakeClock` for testing and a `SystemClock` which uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` or whatever.

I've done this a number of times - it's worked extremely well. It's logical too - effectively you require a "current time service" so that should be injected like any other dependency.

Comment: Thanks, it feels a little odd using DI for things that feel like part of the language itself, but it sounds like this'll work.

Answer (score 6):

I usually inject a date provider into the tested code.  This also helps if you need to switch conventions or otherwise "fix" the time testing code.

Answer (score 2):

Use dependency injection and inject a `TimeProvider` that provides a `getExpiryDate()` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel the TimeProvider/Clock abstraction is too overboard perfectionist (which may very well be the case), consider this instead

Make getCurrentType protected virtual, then create a TestingProductionType decendant of the ProductionType that contains the code you posted. In that type, override the getCurrentType() method to return some deterministic result. In your unit test, create an instance of this TestingProductionType instead.

Viola, the dependency of current time is now removed from your unit tests. The only production code that is now not unit tested is a method with a single line returning new Date(). I could live with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you can check out Mole at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/
`Moles allows to replace any .NET method with a delegate` Just use it to replace Date and have it return what ever you need. Then you don't need to do anything crazy.

-Raul

Answer (score 1):

All three approaches are possible:

1. don't test: lazy man's way
2. use a license that won't expire for ages until you've left the job: cover my ass way
3. use a mock for the current date, such as a TimeProvider: the perfectionist way

I'd go for a comprimise: I'd add the current date as a parameter to the isExpired method, and the isValid method. For your live production code, add a simple `isValid()` no-arg override that calls `isValid(new Date())`. Your test code uses the version that takes the current date as the parameter.

Comment: This option I like best. If the language supports default args, it makes it a bit easier.