# How can I test a class dedicated to returning the current time?

Tags: java, android, junit

I had a class that needed to get the current time. When I started writing tests for that class, I abstracted the time functionality into an external class, which was then injected into the original class and could be mocked while testing. This all works fine, but now I have a Clock class that I would like to test. How can I test this class?

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Clock {
    public long getCurrentTime() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Note: It's very simple at the moment, but I intend to expand it to include more time methods as I continue testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling unit tests with a condition on the current time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459139/handling-unit-tests-with-a-condition-on-the-current-time)

Comment: @EelLee the question is not how to mock the clock (which is already what Scutterman does) but how to test the clock class.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is equivalent to `new Date().getTime()` but more efficient since it's not creating a garbage `Date` object.

Comment: @zapl Thanks for the suggestion, I've refactored my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it does not make sense to test this class, but if you insist, e.g if you are the only person in the project that has a class with 0%
 test coverage ;-) then here a solution:

```
public void testClock() throws InterupteExcdeption {

  Clock testClock = new Clock();
  long time1 = testClock.getCurrentTime();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  long time2 = testClock.getCurrentTime();
  assertTrue(time2 > time1);


}



 public void testClock2() throws InterupteExcdeption {

      Clock testClock = new Clock();
      long time1 = testClock.getCurrentTime();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      long time2 = testClock.getCurrentTime();
      assertTrue(time2 - time1 > 800);

      long time3 = testClock.getCurrentTime();
      long time4 = testClock.getCurrentTime();

      // expecting a value of 0, but make the test defensive, use 100ms
      assertTrue(time4 - time3 < 100);


    }
```

Further tipp: You clock class should implement an `IClock` interface, otherwise it is difficult to replace the system clock with the mock for test cases.

The idea of the IClock is that you can set a MockClock which e.g runs ten times faster, or where you can set the time, which then would be return by getCurrentTime()

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution. I'll also look into implementing `IClock`.

Comment: But how do you know whether the time is the current time?

Comment: You cannot know that, you would have to connect to internet and read the time from a time server. And the system time will nearly never be correct. This is not the goal of the unit test.

Comment: I can pass this test with a simple counter: `private long counter = 0L; public long getCurrentTime() { return counter++; }` - is that all you need?

Comment: You cannot check a clock with unit tests, I told, that it does not make sense. The only effect is that the Clock class is covered by a unit test. The reason for Clock Mocks  is that you cannot and want not check wheter or not the clock works. This is not the job of the unit test. If you are a clock manufacturer things may change and you have to connect your test with a reference clock.

Comment: Updated with a better check : see testClock2 but it does not make much sense, it only test whether your test clock is a real clock and not a mocked clock.

Comment: Thanks for using my answer in your one, that's a weird form of appreciation.

Comment: @GaborSch I have not seen your answer, I even though that there is only one person commenting. By the way you have copied my code, you have the same typing erros in InteruptedException.

Comment: @GaborSch 1) don't copy my code, the typing erros is a proove that you copied it. 2) Your code is different, edit your own code, with your ideas. 3) When I tell you that I have not seen your code than this is a fact.

Comment: OK, my friend _be happy_ with your **"own code"**, but be aware that I copyrighted the `time2 - time1` expression, so anytime you type it you are stealing from me.

Comment: To be honest, it is hard to believe that you have not read my answer. To strictly stick to the facts, I posted it at `16:44:08`, and you updated your answer `16:58:37`, almost 15 minutes later. And you were active on the page, added 2 comments meanwhile.

Comment: I have not seen your answer, I don`t know if it was caused by scrolling down or by InternetExplorer 8 which maybe does not show the pop up "There is a new answer" which I get at home using Safari. By the way I first, named the vars time1 and time2 , and it is obvious to use that name., and time2-time1 I also used 3 years ago, like many other people. Further I have written unit test for my multiSpeedClock some years ago using the 100ms delta check.